# Making too many copies of tables

Tags: sql

I'm writing a query into a table that keeps track of a salesman's status, and keeps track of when they travel. For reference, here are the statuses important to this question:

0: initial value, is working

600: traveling to break

601: on break

603: traveling to lunch

604: at lunch

I'm trying to calculate the total time an employee spends traveling. I am able to return the time to travel and time to lunch using

```
SELECT (cast(c1.status_change_dt as date) - cast(c2.status_change_dt as date)) as LunchTravel, C1.CREW_ID
FROM CREW_STATUS c1, CREW_STATUS c2
WHERE c1.status_id = '603' and c2.status_id = '602'
and c1.mobile_token = c2.mobile_token
```

With the same for the break. Mobile_token is to make sure that it's being returned on the same day (each employee gets a unique token every day).

Status_change_dt is a timestamp

I do the same thing, but the other status_id's to get the BreakTravel time.

So I end up with LunchTravel and BreakTravel, but I feel that creating 4 Crew_Status is inefficient, and it actually runs pretty slow.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you can use a UNION ALL, or a CASE statement.

```
SELECT (cast(c1.status_change_dt as date) - cast(c2.status_change_dt as date))
, CASE WHEN c1.status_id = '603' and c2.status_id = '602' THEN 'Lunch Travel'
,      WHEN c1.status_id = '604' and c2.status_id = '605' THEN 'Break Travel'
END AS travel_type
FROM CREW_STATUS c1, CREW_STATUS c2
WHERE c1.mobile_token = c2.mobile_token
```

OR

```
SELECT (cast(c1.status_change_dt as date) - cast(c2.status_change_dt as date)) as Travel, 'Lunch Travel' AS travel_type, C1.CREW_ID
FROM CREW_STATUS c1, CREW_STATUS c2
WHERE c1.status_id = '603' and c2.status_id = '602'
and c1.mobile_token = c2.mobile_token

UNION ALL

SELECT (cast(c1.status_change_dt as date) - cast(c2.status_change_dt as date)) as Travel, 'Break Travel' AS travel_type, C1.CREW_ID
FROM CREW_STATUS c1, CREW_STATUS c2
WHERE c1.status_id = '605' and c2.status_id = '606'
and c1.mobile_token = c2.mobile_token
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry the question was a little complex. I'll definitely try this though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to join on the statuses (how do you make sure that the row after a 602 is a 603?) I would join by date to get a resultset that gives you the time spent between statuses:

```
SELECT
    CS1.status_id,
    CS2.status_change_dt - CS1.status_change_dt  -- Use date function here
FROM
    Crew_Status CS1
INNER JOIN Crew_Status CS2 ON
    CS2.mobile_token = CS1.mobile_token AND
    CS2.status_change_dt > CS1.status_change_dt
LEFT OUTER JOIN Crew_Status CS3 ON
    CS3.mobile_token = CS1.mobile_token AND
    CS3.status_change_dt > CS1.status_change_dt AND
    CS3.status_change_dt < CS2.status_change_dt
WHERE
    CS3.status_change_dt IS NULL
```

You can then group by the `status_id` and `SUM` the date differences to get totals.

You will probably need to add in some different checks - make sure that the CS1.status_id and CS2.status_id make sense (602 and 603 for example) and account for overly long periods of time (what happens if an employee goes on break, but then no further status gets logged? It might look like they took a 3 day break.

Finally, stop trying to monitor every second of your salesperson's day and let them do their job ;)

Comment: thanks for the help, and haha I'll pass that message on to my boss :)

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports them, it may be sufficient for you to use analytic queries to get the next status for each status that indicates the start of a break:

```
select mobile_token, end_dt - start_dt
from (select status_id, 
             mobile_token,
             status_change_dt as start_dt, 
             lead(status_change_dt) over (partition by mobile_token
                                          order by status_change_dt) as end_dt
      from Crew_Status)
where status_id in (600, 603)
```

Obviously, if you can have a 600 without a 601 (for example), this won't work particularly well (the time period returned would be 600 to whatever happened to come next).

As an aside, it is always a good idea to specify which database you're using, as functionality can vary quite a bit between them.